# Import certain csv/excel data to mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Is there any way to select a certain csv/excel cells then import its data to database? I have a similar program but it only import the first, second, etc. columns.
So here's the php codes for reading excel data and input.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){
        

        echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        

         if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
         {

            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
             while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {
        
              //It wiil insert a row to our subject table from our csv file`
               $sql = "INSERT into subject (`SUBJ_CODE`, `SUBJ_DESCRIPTION`, `UNIT`, `PRE_REQUISITE`,COURSE_ID, `AY`, `SEMESTER`) 
                    values('$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]','$emapData[7]')";
             //we are using mysql_query function. it returns a resource on true else False on error
              $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );
                if(! $result )
                {
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                            window.location = \"index.php\"
                        </script>";
                
                }

             }
             fclose($file);
             //throws a message if data successfully imported to mysql database from excel file
             echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
                        window.location = \"index.php\"
                    </script>";
            
             

             //close of connection
            mysqli_close($conn); 
                
            
            
         }
    }    
?>
```

It only import the selected columns
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utGXb.png)

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqoFQ.png)

What I want is to find a certain cell by reading the cell data and import the data below it. Here's visualization:
[What I want to do:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSuLY.png)

Is there any way to do this? I need help. Thank you

Here is the sample program:
https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/6989/how-import-excelcsv-file-mysql-database-using-php.html

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and isn't the best option in new code.

Comment: Note: Although in many cases PHP is largely case agnostic, it's usually best to stick with conventions like `false` instead of `FALSE`.

Comment: What technical problem are you having with this code? This seems to be roughly the right idea.

Comment: @tadman I want to select a certain cell. This code only select columns and reads data from first row until the end. What I want is select a certain row/column/table and import the data within it. Just like in the image above (What I want to do)

Comment: You can always read all the rows into an array, then look up things in that 2D array as you see fit. A1 is `[0][0]`, C5 is `[4][2]` etc.

Comment: I don't fully understand but I'll research about it. Thanks

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it for just once than you can use some online tools.
If you want to have a code for this than you can do by following code

```
$open = fopen("filename.csv", "r"); // This will open the file for you
$data = fgetcsv($Open, 1000, ","); // Read Line be Line
while (($data = fgetcsv($Open, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
{
  // Read the data    
}
```

Comment: Can you do the code to search for a certain content? For example I want to search for the column titled "Student Names" then import the data (Name of students) below it.